# ModelChoiceField initial value in change form

Tags: python, django, django-forms, django-admin

First the code:

```
class CommentForm(forms.ModelForm):
    categories = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Category.objects.all(), required = False)

class CommentAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form    = CommentForm
```

When I'm editing my comment I'd like it categories field have the initial value of what's been selected when I saved it for the last time. How do I do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
def get_form(self, *args, **kwargs):
        f = super(CommentAdmin, self).get_form(*args, **kwargs)
        f.base_fields['categories'].initial = 1

        return f
```

This code placed in CommentAdmin did the trick...

EDIT:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(CommentForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        self.fields['categories'].initial = self.instance.object_id
```

Or this code placed in CommentForm

Answer (score 1):

You want to have the current model value selected by default in the generated form? If that's the case I think what you are looking for in your view is

```
form = CommentForm(instance = commentinstance)
```

Where `commentinstance` is the instance that you are editing.

(This would be `form = CommentForm(request.POST, instance = commentinstance)` in case of a POST request)

**EDIT**:

If you want to do this in the form, you can just provide the `instance` argument from `__init__`, like so:

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    instance = kwargs.pop('instance', YOUR_DEFAULT_INSTANCE)
    super(CommentForm, self).__init__(instance = instance, *args, **kwargs)
```

That even leaves the default `instance` if you do provide one from your view.

Comment: I was actually looking for a solution to override CommentAdmin (or CommentForm) __init__ method. Since I do this in the admin panel I don't want to write any view function. Something like: self.categories = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset = Category.objects.all(), required = False, initial = {'categories': instance_of_mymodel.pk }) if that makes any sense :P

Comment: In other words: I'd like to plug my code into the code initializing my form.

Comment: 3 years later, added your request. I think this is the simplest way. In general it's better to do in the view, but for exceptional cases you can use this...

Answer (score 0):

I guess there are a few ways to solve this.

Here is how I done before:

```
class MyForm(forms.ModelForm):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if 'ref' in kwargs:
            ref = kwargs['ref']
            item = MyModel.objects.get(pk=ref)
            kwargs['instance'] = item

        super(MyForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

     class Meta:
         model = MyModel
```

The important part is to put your populated model object into the keyword variable instance.