# Django - Can't Initialize Selected Radio Button when using ModelChoiceField with RadioSelect Widget

Tags: django, django-forms

I have a form that I want to be pre-populated with data from a model instance when a user is attempting to update an existing database record. When the form is rendered none of the radio buttons pre-selected even though a model instance has been passed to the ModelForm. In a much larger form than listed below, all of the fields except the radio buttons are pre-populated with the correct data from the model instance. How do I get the correct radio buttons pre-selected?

**My Models:**

```
class TicketType(models.Model):
    type = models.CharField(max_length=15, unique=True)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.type.title()


class TestTicket(models.Model):
    ticket_type = models.ForeignKey(TicketType, to_field='type')
```

**My Form**

```
class TestTicketForm(ModelForm):
    ticket_type = ModelChoiceField(TicketType.objects.all(),
                                   widget=RadioSelect,
                                   empty_label=None)
    class Meta:
        model = TestTicket
        fields = ['ticket_type']
```

**My View**

```
def test_ticket_update(request, ticket_num=None):

    # initialize an update flag to distinguish between a request 
    # to add a new ticket or an update to an existing ticket.
    update_requested = False
    ticket_instance = None

    if ticket_num:
        # This is a request to update a specific ticket. 
        # Attempt to retrieve the ticket or show a 404 error.
        # If a ticket is retrieved, it is locked for editing 
        # by using 'select_for_update()' to prevent a race condition.
        ticket_instance = get_object_or_404(
              TestTicket.objects.select_for_update(),pk=ticket_num)
        update_requested = True

    if request.method == 'POST':
        form = TestTicketForm(request.POST, instance=ticket_instance)
        if form.is_valid():
            ticket = form.save(commit=False)
            ticket.save()
            return HttpResponseRedirect('/tickets/')
    else:

        if update_requested:
            # This is a requested to update an existing ticket. 
            # Bind the ticket data to a form.
            form = TestTicketForm(instance=ticket_instance)
        else:
            form = TestTicketForm()

    return render(request, 'ticket_tracker/ticket_update.html', 
                  { 'form': form, 'ticket': ticket_instance})
```

**My Template**

```
{% block content %}
<div class="container">
        <form action="/tickets/test-ticket/{{ ticket.id }}/" method="post">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p }}

            <div class="form-group">
                <button type="submit">Save</button>
            </div>

        </form>
</div>
{% endblock content %}
```

Comment: I've updated my question to clarify that I want the correct radio button pre-selected, based on the data from the model instance, when the form renders. The radio buttons do appear with the proper values but none are selected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appears this has been [answered here before](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13751728/2967488). In my model I used the `to_field` argument in the creation of the ForeignKey field, but the ModelChoiceField is expecting to use the id when the 'initial' value is passed to it. There are several options to fix this in my example including:

1. Remove the to_field parameter from the ForeignKey field in the model.
2. When creating the form instance in the view, set the 'initial' parameter for the field using the field's id from the model instance, e.g.,

   ```
   form = TestTicketForm(request.POST,
                         instance=ticket_instance,
                         initial={'ticket_type': instance.ticket_type.id)
   ```
3. Set the form field's initial value in the forms `__init__()` method. Again this uses the  field's id from the model instance. For example:

   ```
   class TestTicketForm(ModelForm):
        ticket_type = ModelChoiceField(TicketType.objects.all(), 
                                       widget=RadioSelect, 
                                       empty_label=None)

   def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
       super(TestTicketForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

       if self.instance is not None:
           self.initial['ticket_type'] = self.instance.ticket_type.id
   ```

Option #1 above would require a schema and data migrations in my database. Options #2 and #3 are similar but I chose option #3 since it makes my view code slightly cleaner.