# Django prepopulated radiobutton not working

Tags: django, django-forms

I want a prepopulated radiobutton using django form.But cant make it.I can use like this passing model and checking whether it is true or false .but how can use djangoform for that.

```
<input type="radio" value="True" name="power_windows"
                                                               {% if interiorfeatures.power_windows %}checked="true"{% endif %}>Yes
```

My code sample is given below

### Form

```
   class InteriorfeaturesForm(forms.ModelForm):
      class Meta:
        model = InteriorFeatures
        fields = ['power_steering', 'power_windows']
      power_steering =forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=InteriorFeatures.objects.all(),
                                widget=forms.RadioSelect())
```

Model

```
---
    class InteriorFeatures(models.Model):
        class Meta:
            db_table = 'interior_features'
        variant = models.ForeignKey(Variant)
        power_steering = models.BooleanField(default=False)
        power_windows = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

### View

```
try:
    interiorfeatures = InteriorFeatures.objects.get(variant=variant)
except InteriorFeatures.DoesNotExist:
            interiorfeatures = None
    interiorform = InteriorfeaturesForm(instance=interiorfeatures)
return render(request, 'general/specifications.html',
                      {'dimensionsform': DimensionForm, 'engineform': EngineForm, 'brakeform': BrakeForm,
                       'capacityform': CapacityForm, 'mileageform': MileageForm, 'priceform': PriceForm,
                       'steeringform': SteeringForm, 'interiorform': interiorform, 'interiorfeatures': interiorfeatures,
                       'variant': variant, 'price': price, 'steering': steering, 'wheel': wheel, 'wheelform': WheelForm,
                       'dimensions': dimensions, 'engine': engine, 'brake': brake, 'capacity': capacity,
                       'mileage': mileage})
```

### html

--
{{interiorform.power_steering}}

Comment: Why do you render `power_windows` manually in the template?

Comment: It's already answered here. Please refer : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20169358/django-cant-initialize-selected-radio-button-when-using-modelchoicefield-with

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to add `power_windows` to your form fields like this:

```
class InteriorfeaturesForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = InteriorFeatures
        fields = ['power_steering', 'power_windows']
    power_steering =forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=InteriorFeatures.objects.all(),
                                           widget=forms.RadioSelect())
    power_windows = forms.BooleanField()
```

By default it would give you a checkbox, but if you insist on using radio button, you could do this:

```
power_windows = forms.TypedChoiceField(coerce=lambda x: x == 'True',
                                       choices=((False, 'False'), (True, 'True')),
                                       widget=forms.RadioSelect)
```

Comment: Thanks Shang Wang.That is what i want :)